# Get a mongo Document having juste a specific type of document in an array

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have an issue with my mongo queries.
I have two documents :

First one :

```
{
  "_id": "GRP_TARIF_2927097",

  "ENT_ENS_TARIF": {
    "id": "1",
    "type": "ENT_ENS_TARIF"
  },
  "id": "1",
  "KEY_CODE_GP_TARIF": "1",
  "schemaVersion": "1",
  "ENT_ENS_TARIF_MULTI": [
    {
      "type": "ENT_ENS_TARIF",
      "id": "1"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "type": "ENT_ENS_TARIF2"
    }
  ]
}
```

AND the second One :

```
  "_id": "GRP_TARIF_2927066",

  "ENT_ENS_TARIF": {
    "id": "10",
    "type": "ENT_ENS_TARIF"
  },
  "id": "6",
  "KEY_CODE_GP_TARIF": "1",
  "schemaVersion": "1",
  "ENT_ENS_TARIF_MULTI": [
    {
      "type": "ENT_ENS_TARIF",
      "id": "4"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "type": "ENT_ENS_TARIF"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to find a query that will give the document which has only the ENT_ENS_TARIF_MULTI.type ENT_ENS_TARIF in his array, not like the first document which has ENT_ENS_TARIF2 in his array and a specific ENT_ENS_TARIF_MULTI.id

This is what i tried so far :

```
{
 filter: {
  $and: [
   {
    'ENT_ENS_TARIF_MULTI.id': {
     $in: [
      '1'
     ]
    },
    'ENT_ENS_TARIF_MULTI.type': 'ENT_ENS_TARIF2'
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

```
{
 filter: {
  ENT_ENS_TARIF_MULTI: {
   $elemMatch: {
    type: 'ENT_ENS_TARIF',
    id: '1'
   }
  }
 }
}
```

None gave me what i wanted they always give me the first document even though i want them to give me nothing ...
Thanks for your time !
Have a nice day !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i managed to find a way of getting only the documents that i wanted, here is the answer :

```
{ENT_ENS_TARIF_MULTI: {$not: { $elemMatch: { type: { $ne: 'ENT_ENS_TARIF' } }}},'ENT_ENS_TARIF_MULTI.id': '3'}
```

the first segment of the query is how i managed to get only the documents having the right type